# Spring FactoryBean

Tags: spring, factory, spring-bean

I'm trying to grasp Spring's FactoryBean and I've had and issue. Could you please see my sources below and answer. It's my app context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="SHADigest" class="com.dtoryanik.spring.factorybean.MessageDigestFactoryBean">
        <property name="algorithmName">
            <value>SHA1</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="defaultDigest" class="com.dtoryanik.spring.factorybean.MessageDigestFactoryBean"/>

    <bean id="digester" class="com.dtoryanik.spring.factorybean.MessageDigester">
        <property name="messageDigest1">
            <ref local="SHADigest"/>
        </property>
        <property name="messageDigest2">
            <ref local="defaultDigest"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

It's a factory bean actually:

```
public class MessageDigestFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<MessageDigest>{

    private String algorithmName = "MD5";
    private MessageDigest messageDigest = null;

    @Override
    public MessageDigest getObject() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.getObject()");
        return messageDigest;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        System.out.println("<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.getObjectType()");
        return MessageDigest.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        System.out.println("<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.isSingleton()");
        return true;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstructHandler() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        System.out.println("<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.postConstructHandler()");
        messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithmName);
    }

    public void setAlgorithmName(String algorithmName) {
        this.algorithmName = algorithmName;
    }
}
```

There is another class - MessageDigester but it does not do anything helpful for topic. And I have a main-method class:

```
public class MessageDigestDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
    ctx.load("classpath:app-ctx.xml");
    ctx.refresh();

    MessageDigester messageDigester = (MessageDigester) ctx.getBean("digester");
    messageDigester.digest("Hello World!");
}
```

}

The issue is in my output. It seems I have a double instantiating. Methods isSingleton(), getObject() are called two times for each bean (although I retrieve only 2 instances from factory). Why does it occur? Maybe I do something wrong?

```
<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.postConstructHandler()
<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.postConstructHandler()
<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.isSingleton()
<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.getObject()
<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.isSingleton()
<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.getObject()
<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.isSingleton()
<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.getObjectType()
<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.isSingleton()
<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.getObjectType()
```

Comment: I have a similar issue with my project:  https://github.com/djangofan/spring-bean-factory-example , except that the answer provided here doesn't really give me enough of a hint to solve.  If I do figure it out, ill update the project at that url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modified your `MessageDigestFactoryBean` class so that it outputs `algorithmName` as well, this will help to clear out the case. After that change, the output is:

```
<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.postConstructHandler() SHA1
<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.postConstructHandler() MD5
<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.isSingleton() SHA1
<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.getObject() SHA1
<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.isSingleton() MD5
<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.getObject() MD5
<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.isSingleton() SHA1
<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.getObjectType() SHA1
<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.isSingleton() MD5
<> MessageDigestFactoryBean.getObjectType() MD5
```

Let's try to analyze this output.

1. You have declared two `MessageDigestFactoryBean` instances, so when Spring discovers them in context, it initializes them, and in process calls the method annotated with `@PostConstruct` - **`MessageDigestFactoryBean.postConstructHandler()`**.
2. Then as Spring discovers `digester` bean, it tries to obtain it's dependencies. Spring sees that dependency is `FactoryBean`, so it eventually calls [FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.html). This method first checks if the bean is singleton, calling **`MessageDigestFactoryBean.isSingleton()`**. If the bean is singleton, it first tries to obtain reference to it from factory bean objects cache. Since this is the first time this bean is referenced, it's not yet cached, so reference is obtained via **`MessageDigestFactoryBean.getObject()`**, cached and then returned. Since you have two factory beans referenced in `digester`, obviously this process is repeated for each one.
3. After initialization is complete, Spring tries to publish [ContextRefreshedEvent](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextRefreshedEvent.html) to the lifecycle processor, so it searches all bean definitions for an instance that implements [Lifecycle](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/Lifecycle.html) interface. Basically Spring loops through all beans defined in context, checking for singleton bean of matching type (actually there are more checks, but we're interested only in these). In process of this, for factory bean **`MessageDigestFactoryBean.isSingleton()`** is called to determine whether object is singleton, and **`MessageDigestFactoryBean.getObjectType()`** is called to check whether object's type is assignable from `Lifecycle` interface. Again, since you have two instances of `MessageDigestFactoryBean`, each of these methods is called twice.

That's what happens when you call `ctx.refresh()`. This is just over the top look and obviously a lot more is done by Spring under the hood, but that's all I can see related to your output. Hope this answers your first question.

Now for the second question - no, you did not do anything wrong, the output you see just reflects how Spring functions internally.

Comment: Thank you very much, Dmitry, for clarifying! But when I try to comment the `ctx.refresh()` line I get a `NullPointerException` in a place where I would like to get already initialized MessageDigest. Actually, it's in MessageDigester class which I did not write about in first message.

Comment: It happens because dependencies are actually resolved in `ctx.refresh()`. `ctx.load()` only loads bean definitions. So both messageDigest isntances are null, hence NPE. You have to call refresh() to get functioning app context when using [GenericXmlApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/GenericXmlApplicationContext.html) with default constructor and this is reflected in javadoc. Alternatively, you could've just passed `"classpath:context.xml"` as a parameter to constructor, that way `refresh` would be called automatically.

Comment: The things fell into place right now! Thank you very much for explanations.

Comment: No problem :) Also, if you're satisfied with the answer, please mark it as accepted. Cheers!