# Why do my 2 Spring Java FactoryBean's seem to get loaded more than once?

Tags: spring, lazy-loading, factory

Why do my 2 Spring Java **FactoryBean**'s seem to get loaded more than once?  I created this project that I intended to have 2 lazy-loaded **AbstractFactoryBean** instances.  My project uses a pure Java AppConfig method (rather than **application.xml** method) and is built with Gradle.  Maybe I am doing this wrong or maybe this is normal?

https://github.com/djangofan/spring-lazy-loading-beans-example

So, when I run my project, I expect the 2 beans to get instantiated with id numbers  of 1  and 2   but instead they get ID numbers 4 and 5, which is wierd, because that tells me that the **.getNextNumberInSequence(1)** gets called 5 times in total.

```
public class EmployeeFactoryBean extends AbstractFactoryBean<Object>
  @Autowired
  private ApplicationConfig applicationConfig;
  @Autowired
  private SimpleIdGenerator simpleIdGenerator;
...
  @Override
  protected Object createInstance() throws Exception
  {
    EmployeeDTO employee = new EmployeeDTO();
    employee.setId(simpleIdGenerator.getNextNumberInSequence(1));
    employee.setType(factoryType);
    employee.setFirstName(applicationConfig.getDefaultFirstName());
    employee.setLastName(applicationConfig.getDefaultLastName());
    return employee;
  }
....
```

Now, this is somewhat ok, since I just wanted both bean instances to have their own unique number, BUT I am confused why my particular code is incrementing the number 3x before ids get set on the 2 beans I wanted to instantiate.

This might give you an idea on how I tried instantiate the beans **on-demand** (which means I am not intending Spring to auto load them when context starts up):

```
EmployeeDTO manager = (EmployeeDTO)context.getBean("manager");
System.out.println(manager);

EmployeeDTO director = (EmployeeDTO)context.getBean("director");
System.out.println(director);
```

Found a similar issue that someone else reported but its different enough that it doesn't answer my question:  [Spring FactoryBean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786618/spring-factorybean)

Comment: I can't verify this at the moment, but look at `AbstractFactoryBean#getEarlySingletonInstance`, which pre-initializes an instance to use during context setup.

Comment: Plug your breakpoint in the id generator's code and look up the stacktrace. Should give you a hint.

Comment: Ok, I was not able to put a breakpoint in that location since my IntelliJ-IDEA IDE refused to stop at that breakpoint.  I did update my project to enable debug output for  `org.springframework.beans` and it gives me more info but still trying to interpret.

Comment: Ok, I was able to determine that `.afterPropertiesSet` on line 134 of AbstractFactoryBean is calling the method 3x before I ask for the beans in my code.  Presumably because  the method `.afterPropertiesSet` is being called 3x by Spring itself during startup?  Now I just need to figure out why OR how to adjust my code.   I was using FactoryBean because I was expecting the beans to lazy load once I call them, not automatically during Spring startup.

Comment: You can use a `@Lazy` bean for that.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis -  Thanks!  That fixed it for me.  Just changed my code to user `@Lazy`  and now it works just like I wanted it to.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm investigating your current code at the moment and you've got a messed up case that doesn't seem like it could happen. Do you want me to provide an answer here?

Comment: Sure, you can answer. I'll mark you as having answered me.   Im not sure if using Lazy in combination with FactoryBean makes sense anyways, does it?

Comment: Ah, nvm. It's kind of long to answer and all over the place in the internals of Spring. It's an edge case that is quite unlikely to happen. I'm glad you have your solution.

Comment: Just for you, your `@Autowired Environment` was `null`, not yet injected which caused the two factory beans to fail initialization and retry.  Another solution would've been to inject the property values directly into the beans with `@Value("defaults.lastName")` (and a property resolver).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks, Ill debug and try to fix that. Thanks.